# Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'CdkDragDrop<string [], string[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular-material, typeguards

I'm looking at the [reorderable columns example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnnbpxldjgob?file=src%2Fapp%2F.%2Ftable-reorderable-example.html) on stackblitz.

In particular I see the html

```
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" 
       cdkDropList
       cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
       (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
```

I've defined the drop inside MytableComponent

```
export class MytableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<MytableItem>;
  dataSource: MytableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name', 'dateOfBirth'];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.displayedColumns, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource = new MytableDataSource();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

The build fails with an error

```
Error: src/app/mytable/mytable.component.html:5:35 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CdkDragDrop<string[], string[]>'.
  Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'CdkDragDrop<string[], string[]>': previousIndex, currentIndex, item, container, and
3 more.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have set a stricter type checking than the example in the initial settings of the project.

After a search I see that

```
  drop(event: Event)  {
      if (isDragDrop(event)) {
        moveItemInArray(this.displayedColumns, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
      }
    }
```

compiles successfully, when I declare a

```
function isDragDrop(object: any): object is CdkDragDrop<string[]> {
  return 'previousIndex' in object;
}
```

Of course I have to import the `DragDropModule` in the `app.module.ts`
and now I **can reorder the columns**

BTW, it is also possible to load and save the columns' order from local storage with convenient helpers, for example - with an  `@Input() ID: string | undefined;` - in `mytable.component.ts` I've added also:

```
  onSaveOrder() {
    if (!this.ID) {
      console.log('my-table ID not set!');
      return;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('my-table-cols-' + this.ID, this.displayedColumns.join(','));
    console.log(`table ID ${ this.ID } columns order saved ${ this.displayedColumns }`);
  }
  onLoadOrder() {
    if (!this.ID) {
      console.log('my-table ID not set!');
      return;
    }
    const saved = localStorage.getItem('my-table-cols-' + this.ID);
    if (saved) {
      this.displayedColumns = saved.split(',');  
      console.log(`table ID ${ this.ID } columns order loaded ${saved}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`table ID ${ this.ID } nothing was saved`);
    }
  }
```

Usage in `app.component.html`

```
  <h3>My Table Rowss</h3>
  <app-mytable ID="MyTable1"></app-mytable>
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply importing the `DragDropModule` from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop' into your component's module fixes the problem.

*Aside:* I also followed the same [example on the Angular Material site](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-reorderable) and have strict type checking enabled. It looks like a strict type checking issue at first, but it's just another example of a distracting error message produced by the compiler when you forget to import a module. I have yet to witness strict type checking cause a component to break.

Answer (score 6):

For Drag and drop to work flawless conditions to be met are as follows:

1. In the app.module.ts file DragDrop module should be imported as mentioned below:

   ```
   import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
   imports: [ 
   DragDropModule
   ],
   ```
2. In the Compoenent.html add the below attributes to the div or any selector that you want to implement drag and drop:

   ```
   <div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
              <mat-card
                cdkDrag
                *ngFor="let element of array" //array is the one that is 
                       given as input to the moveItemInArray() in drop()
              >
                <div>
                    {{ element  }}
                </div>
              </mat-card>
            </div>
   ```
3. In the Component.ts file in which drag and drop to be implemented below code should be implemented:

   ```
    import { CdkDrag, CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
       moveItemInArray(this.array, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
   ```

   where, 'this.array' is the array that is traversed for drag-drop in HTML file,
   'moveItemInArray()' rearranges the array elements based on drag-drop indexes
   placed as received by the event.

This would solve all the errors that is being emitted while implementing drag drop.

Comment: how on earth did you know the module.ts import is beyond me... thanks!